# Airflow Custom Operator Waiting In Scheduled Status

Tags: python, airflow

I try to customize SSHOperator like CustomSSHOperator. Because I need to assign dynamic values to ssh_conn_id and pool variables of SSHOperator. However these two are not in template_fields. So I've create a custom class like below

```py
class CustomSSHOperator(SSHOperator):
    template_fields: Sequence[str] = ('command', 'remote_host', 'ssh_conn_id', 'pool')
    template_fields_renderers = {"command": "bash", "remote_host": "str", "ssh_conn_id": "str", "pool": "str"}

    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

And I'm creating dag like below

```py
VM_CONN_ID = "vm-{vm_name}"
VM_POOL = "vm-{vm_name}"
with DAG(dag_id="my_dag", tags=["Project", "Team"],
      start_date=datetime(2022, 9, 27), schedule_interval=None,
     ) as dag:
tasks = []
    vm1_task = CustomSSHOperator(task_id='vm1_task',
                                 # ssh_conn_id='vm-112',
                                 #pool='vm-112',
                                 ssh_conn_id=VM_CONN_ID.format(vm_name="{{dag_run.conf['vm1']}}"),
                                 pool=VM_CONN_ID.format(vm_name="{{dag_run.conf['vm1']}}"),
                                 get_pty=True,
                                 command="d=$(date) && echo $d > my_file.txt"
                                 )

    vm2_task = CustomSSHOperator(task_id='vm2_task',
                                 # ssh_conn_id='vm-140',
                                 #pool='vm-140',
                                 ssh_conn_id=VM_CONN_ID.format(vm_name="{{dag_run.conf['vm2']}}"),
                                 pool=VM_CONN_ID.format(vm_name="{{dag_run.conf['vm2']}}"),
                                 get_pty=True,
                                 command="d=$(date) && echo $d > my_file.txt"
                                 )
```

Basically, I can see the rendered values from the UI. However my tasks are waiting as in the image

[image]

I also indicate that if I change the dag like below(just populating pool variable as static, ssh_conn_id is still dynamic variable), It works

```py
VM_CONN_ID = "vm-{vm_name}"
VM_POOL = "vm-{vm_name}"

with DAG(dag_id="my_dag", tags=["Project", "Team"], start_date=datetime(2022, 9, 27), schedule_interval=None,) as dag:
    tasks = []
    vm1_task = CustomSSHOperator(task_id='vm1_task',
                                 # ssh_conn_id='vm-112',
                                 pool='vm-112',
                                 ssh_conn_id=VM_CONN_ID.format(vm_name="{{dag_run.conf['vm1']}}"),
                                 #pool=VM_CONN_ID.format(vm_name="{{dag_run.conf['vm1']}}"),
                                 get_pty=True,
                                 command="d=$(date) && echo $d > my_file.txt"
                                 )

    vm2_task = CustomSSHOperator(task_id='vm2_task',
                                 # ssh_conn_id='vm-140',
                                 pool='vm-140',
                                 ssh_conn_id=VM_CONN_ID.format(vm_name="{{dag_run.conf['vm2']}}"),
                                 #pool=VM_CONN_ID.format(vm_name="{{dag_run.conf['vm2']}}"),
                                 get_pty=True,
                                 command="d=$(date) && echo $d > my_file.txt"
                                 )
```

dag_run.conf parameter is {"vm1": "112", "vm2": "140"}

I couldn't find the reason. I'd be appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Template fields are rendered **after** the task has been scheduled, while the task `pool` field is used **before** the task is scheduled (by the Airflow scheduler itself).

This is the reason why a template cannot be used for the `pool` field. See also [this discussion](https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/21144).

What is happening in your case is that the task remains stuck in the `scheduled` state because it is associated with a non-existent pool (actually it is `vm-{{dag_run.conf['vm1']}}`, that is, evaluated before the rendering).

You should have evidence of this in the scheduler logs:

```
Tasks using non-existent pool 'vm-{{dag_run.conf['vm1']}}' will not be scheduled
```

As a proof, you can create a new pool named exactly `vm-{{dag_run.conf['vm1']}}` and you will see that the task will be executed.

Only later the `pool` field will be rendered, and that's why you see the expected rendered values from the UI. But that's not what the scheduler saw.